# cross-platform SignalR -windows store / windows phone

Tags: signalr, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I saw in the NDC 2013 that the talk Stuart Lodge gave shows a little JABBR written for Windows Store.

I am looking to try to use SignalR on both WindowsPhone and WindowsStore, but I can't find a portable SignalR library to use.

Does anyone know how SignalR can be used in a PCL?

Thank you
Sergio

Comment: This type of question is not best suited for StackOverflow. Non-code problems directed specifically to a person would be better served to contact that person directly.

Comment: this? https://github.com/Redth/JabbRIsMobile

Comment: @valdetero I think this is a code problem -"how do I use signalr cross-platform?" but it's poorly phrased. I also never recommend contacting people directly - see http://slodge.blogspot.ca/2013/06/my-standard-reply-to-mvvmcross-support.html?m=1 - better IMO to take the time to ask a good question accessible to all - a well worded, well tagged question about portable signalr would attract answers from the Msoft teams and would be an excellent public reference for others. All IMO.

Comment: @Sergio welcome to stack ovverflow - please try not to address questions to me (or anyone) specifically. Instead if you can take time asking questions about what you are trying to do, then it's truly amazing some of the answers you will get sometimes. I and others sometimes spend hours answering a single question - the better shaped the question, the more we will be encouraged to help. Stuart

Comment: Great, thank you Stuart.
Sorry for my ill formatted question, I'll be better in the future.

I've found the code on github suggested above (JabbRIsMobile) but unfortunately looks like the piece of code I was after (JabbR.Client.Store) was not commited in any revision.

Anyway, thank you for the great work you been doing for the community.

Sergio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jabbr sample shown in that demo was a port of @redth's jabbrismobile repo - https://github.com/Redth/JabbRIsMobile

Because the original author hadn't used portable code, the winrt port used file linking rather than PCLs.

However, portable SignalR is planned - I've talked to a couple of the team about this and they said a subset of SignalR client will be available as a pcl at some point.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of the [Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client) NuGet package has support for Windows Phone 8 and Silverlight 5 via portable class libraries.

Comment: Installing this package is giving an error in Json:

Install-Package : Could not install package 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.6'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-win+net45+MonoAndroid16+MonoTouch40+sl40+wp71', but the 
package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
+ Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client -Pre

Do I need to install any other package first?

Comment: The problem you are hitting is that Xamarin tools modify Visual Studio's installation, which breaks NuGet's logic for installing certain packages built for portable. It's a known NuGet bug/limitation - tracked by https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2926. There's not a real good workaround, other than manually referencing the binaries or uninstalling the Xamarin tools, install the package, then reinstall.

Comment: I see, but even if I remove the **-Pre-** command line, it still fails. By "manual" you mean downloading/clone the project and add into my project?

Comment: Well, with minor tweaks as shown in the issue above, I managed to install JSon + the 2 BCL packages, but now who fails is SignalR itself:

Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client 2.0.0-beta2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-win+net45+sl40+wp80', but the 
package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

tried with wp7.1 or wp8, no success. Any other idea?

Comment: @user2677153 It looks like you are targeting Silverlight 4 in the portable library you're trying to install into.  Try switching to Silverlight 5.

Comment: If I try to change to 5, its a noop:



The following frameworks will be selected automatically because they support all of the available functionality that is portable between the other frameworks you have selected: Silverlight 4.



even trying to remove SL is a noop, the dialog puts it back...